# jquery on change after ajax being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got jquery that gets fired after every ajax complete

here's a console view

[image]

`education-script` line 23-45

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.start-date').datepicker();
    $('.end-date').datepicker();

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ });

    $('.education-level').off();

    $('body').on('change', '.education-level', (function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value);

        if (value == 'other') {
            $('.education-other').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.education-level-error').addClass('hidden');
        } else if(value == '') {
            $('.education-level-error').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('.education-other').addClass('hidden');
            $('.education-level-error').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }));
})
```

it's logging twice, tried unbinding change with no success. 
the other call in `education-script` 52-65

```
$('.education-level').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);

    if (value == 'other') {
        $('.education-other').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.education-level-error').addClass('hidden');
    } else if(value == '') {
        $('.education-level-error').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('.education-other').addClass('hidden');
        $('.education-level-error').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

and the select html

```
    <select class="selectpicker education-level" title="Choose one of the following...">
        <option></option>
        <option>University</option>
        <option>College</option>
        <option>High school</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
```

**UPDATE**

I did a console log of the parent of `this` when change detected the response explains the issue, `selectpicker` creates a friendly select box as a duplicate of the original and the change is calling both of them but only one actually is in use.

[image]

Comment: `bind()` and `unbind()` are deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/  You might want to look into `on()` and `off()` instead

Comment: instead of binding in the ajax complete, try doing a [delegated bind](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) - that way it will only be bound once rather than each time the ajax completes

Comment: What is purpose of attaching `change` event with `ajaxComplete` event?

Comment: there's a link that gets the form via ajax get and appends it to the html.

Comment: I've tried it with `.on` but returns the same error